# Ionic, cordova and iOS emulator conflict port (8080)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ios-simulator, port

I all,

I'm developing an app with Ionic 3.
This app send REST HTTP request to a Java backend running on Tomcat (port 8080)

When I test with ionic serve command, it's running normally.

But When I test with iOS simulator with Ionic and Cordova, the HTTP request doesn't work : (HTTP 404)

When à test a REST web service by Chrome it doesn't work (HTTP 404).

When I stop Tomcat, Chrome return HTTP 404 !!!

When I stop iOS emulator with Tomcat is running, the REST web service return a good result to Chrome.

I don't know who use 8080 port ? Cordova ? iOS emulator ? 
How can I release this port ? (I would like keep this port for Tomcat)

Thanks.